# When trying to link my Shader I get the Error Code "error c5145 must write to gl_position"

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw

I'm using vs2019 as my IDE, GLEW(ver2.1.0), glm and GLfw(3.3.2) as libraries. When trying to link the Vertex Shader I get the afor mentioned error code.

> ```
> ERROR::SHADER::Programm::LINK_ERROR
> Vertex info
> -----------
> (0) : error C5145: must write to gl_Position
> ```

Below you can find the Code to compile and link the shader. Compiling seems to get done without any problems but the link wont work for the vertex shader, fragment shader seems to be fine.

```
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H


#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/glew.h>

class Shader
{
public:
    GLuint Program;

    // Erstellen des Shaders
    Shader(const GLchar* vertexPath, const GLchar* fragmentPath)
    {
        // Speicher und Laden der Shader
        std::string vertexCode;
        std::string fragmentCode;
        std::ifstream verShaderFile;
        std::ifstream fragShaderFile;
        //sicherstellen das ifstreams ausnahmen werfen können
        verShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit);
        fragShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit);
        try
        {
            //öffnen der Datein
            verShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
            fragShaderFile.open(fragmentPath);
            std::stringstream verShaderStream, fragShaderStream;
            //Inhalte der Datei-Buffer in den Streams speichern
            verShaderStream << verShaderFile.rdbuf();
            fragShaderStream << fragShaderFile.rdbuf();
            //Datein schließen
            verShaderFile.close();
            fragShaderFile.close();
            //Stream in String umwandeln
            vertexCode = verShaderStream.str();
            fragmentCode = fragShaderStream.str();
        }
        catch (std::ifstream::failure e)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ" << std::endl;
        }
        const GLchar *verShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
        const GLchar *fragShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();

        //Compilen der Shader
        //leere Shader erstellen
        GLuint vertex;
        GLuint fragment;
        GLint success;
        GLchar infoLog[512];

        //Vertex Shader
        vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &verShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertex);
        //Compile Fehler ausgeben
        glGetShaderiv(vertex, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }

        //Fragment Shader
        fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fragShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragment);
        //Output of compiling errors
        glGetShaderiv(fragment, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }

        //Shader Program erstellen
        this->Program = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(this->Program, vertex);
        glAttachShader(this->Program, fragment);
        glLinkProgram(this->Program);
        // Linking Errors ausgeben
        glGetProgramiv(this->Program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(this->Program, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::Programm::LINK_ERROR\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }
        //Löschen der Shader nach Linken mit dem Programm
        glDeleteShader(vertex);
        glDeleteShader(fragment);
    }
    //nutzen des Shaders
    void ShaderStarten()
    {
        glUseProgram(this->Program);
    }
};
#endif // !SHADER_H
```

This is the vertex shader itself:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;


out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;


void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4( position, 1.0f );
    ourColor = color;

    TexCoord = vec2( texCoord.x, 1.0 - texCoord.y);
}
```

Would really appreciate the help.

edit. here is the fragment shader someone requested

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture1;

void main()
{
    color = texture (ourTexture1, TexCoord);
}
```

edit2. added the semicolon to `color = texture (ourTexture1, TexCoord);` and added the TexCoord back to the vertex shader. Issue is still present.

Comment: Please provide the code for the fragment program as they might be error within it

Comment: That's why I asked for fragment code

Comment: @Rixment the previous comment was directed at a now deleted one. The fragment shader does not seem to be the issue as the Info log states it is an issue with the vertex shader.

Comment: If you print out the shader code in your program, does it print correctly?

Comment: Where is the `LINK_ERROR` string coming from?  The link failure case message is in...German (`LINK_FEHLER`)?

Comment: @Bearowl Are you sure the shader files are successfully read? See [OpenGL shaders don't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47853523/opengl-shaders-dont-compile/47853880#47853880)

Comment: @Bearowl If you're using TexCoord in your fragment shouldn't you pass them from your vertex shader, just as you did the same with the colour? Don't know model 3 of shaders but I remember it was necessary in model 2.

Comment: @genpfault sry my bad I changed it to english in the message but forgot to do so inside the code.

Comment: @Rabbid If they would not compile I would get a compile error not a link error, I do have failure case messages for compiling aswell.

Comment: @Rixment There used to be TexCoord in the vertex shader while searching for the error I took those out. Gonna try adding those in again after grabbing some food.

Comment: @Bearowl Use `vShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);`

Comment: @Rabbid76 what is the difference between the two? I'm already using `std::ifstream::badbit` I did print out the code of the shaderfiles it is correctly read by the ifstream.

Comment: @Bearowl Read the answer to [OpenGL shaders don't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47853523/opengl-shaders-dont-compile/47853880#47853880) - if `std::ifstream::open` fails, the `failbit` state flag is set but not the `badbit`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks for the info. Found the error now gonna post that.

Comment: One more thing, was it allowed to write 1.0f instead of 1.0?

Comment: @Rixment Could that lead to errors? if so I better remove that f

Comment: @Bearowl Unfortunately it seems not, but if I'm not mistaken it wasn't the case in previous iterations of shaders (yes I could be wrong)

Comment: @Bearowl Still I don't know the reason why you'd use f after const in shader programs. I know it's very tempting coming from c++ background but in shader programs I've never used it

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what's wrong, I don't quite understand why though. I was keeping the vertex and fragment programm files in a subfolder as seperate files. When calling for the Shader I gave the file name and subfolder as input `Shader myShader("Shader/core.vs", "Shader/core.frag")` like this. This lead to problems for the vertex shader not for the fragment shader though. Which I don't really get if I'm honest.

I'm sorry that this trivial mistake cost you so much time. Thank you for all of your input though I learned some new things.

edit. So you should probably check out the thread Rabbid76 mentioned in a comment under the question.